# Github pages and github project sites with personal domain name

Tags: github, github-pages

I successfully moved my blog to github pages(www.strayed-bits.net). However, I cannot access my project site: rmuktader.github.io/bootstrap

Is there a way to make custom domain name work for both github pages and github project sites? Or do I have to forget about personal domain name and stick with rmuktader.github.io?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, pointing to `rmuktader.github.io/bootstrap` leads server to look for `rmuktader.github.io/bootstrap/index.html` which doesn't exist.

The only thing available at this url ([from your last commit](https://github.com/rmuktader/bootstrap/commit/711906d41c264beeeb0e54a89c8a47912bb03d25)) is a folder containing a `starter_template` folder, but no index.html at the root. So, 404 !

You can move all the `starter_template` content to your root an commit the changes.
This will send, you will now have your `index.html` at the root, and everithing will be ok.